# Image Uploading from android application to Server is not working

Tags: php, android, server, android-camera

I'm developing an android app which requires to upload the image taken with camera to the server. I used a tutorial for this and imported the project 
[from this link, refer this for android code](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/)

My PHP file which is indicating success of the image and returning me the URL but the image is not found on the server. I am not able to troubleshoot this problem.

My PHP file code is:

```
 <?php

// Path to move uploaded files
$target_path = "Upload_image_ANDROID/";

// array for final json respone
$response = array();

// getting server ip address
$server_ip = '216.86.147.200';

// final file url that is being uploaded
$file_upload_url = 'http://' . $server_ip . '/' . 'sss_api' . '/' . $target_path;


if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
    $target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

    // reading other post parameters
   // $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    //$website = isset($_POST['website']) ? $_POST['website'] : '';

    $response['file_name'] = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    //$response['email'] = $email;
    //$response['website'] = $website;

    try {
        // Throws exception incase file is not being moved
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
            // make error flag true
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = 'Could not move the file!';
        }

        // File successfully uploaded
        $response['message'] = 'File uploaded successfully!';
        $response['error'] = false;
        $response['file_path'] = $file_upload_url . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Exception occurred. Make error flag true
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    // File parameter is missing
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = 'Not received any file!F';
}

// Echo final json response to client
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Can you add some echo statements to see what the values of your variables are

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the tutorial to the end and your Android App is working as expected on your device, the problem is more on the server side due to **permission**, your server doesn't allow you to save the file.

Try to set the location to a folder where your application will have permission to write to or change **htaccess** you can get more info on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html